# Why is the matlab filter order limited by one third of the length of data minus one?

Tags: matlab, filter

I have a question regarding filters in matlab.

1. I wonder why the filter order in MATLAB is limited by `n_order = floor(length(t)/3)-1` as in the example below? Is this a numerical requirement for filter to work?
2. Also, `n_order` is equal to the size of the window, thus this limit permits creating 3 windows with the maximum order size. Is there a way to create more windows with the same filter order?

The code below is just to give an example to you.

```
t = linspace(0,4*pi,1000);
rng default  %initialize random number generator
x = sin(t) + 0.25*rand(size(t));
dt = t(2)-t(1);
Fs = 1/dt;   % Sampling frequency
f_band = [0.01 2];
n_order = floor(length(t)/3)-1; % max order (will result in 3 windows)
n_wind_filtLen = n_order+1; % step-length of windows
df = Fs/n_wind_filtLen; % frequency bin size
b = fir1(n_order,f_band/(Fs/2),'bandpass',hamming(n_order+1)); % a=1;
x_fil = filtfilt(b,1,x); % a=1;
figure;
plot(t, x,'-k','linewidth',2); hold on;
plot(t, x_fil,'-.r','linewidth',2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This requirement comes from the function `filtfilt`. You can find its documentation [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filtfilt.html).

By typing `help filtfilt`, you can read:

> The length of the input X must be more than three times the filter
>       order, defined as max(length(B)-1,length(A)-1).

This limitation is confirmed in the function's source code:

```
nb = numel(b);
nfilt = max(nb,na);   
nfact = max(1,3*(nfilt-1));  % length of edge transients
if Npts <= nfact             % input data too short
    error(message('signal:filtfilt:InvalidDimensionsDataShortForFiltOrder',num2str(nfact)));
end
```

If you want to increase the order, you have to increase the length of your data.

The other limitation, comes from the function `fir1`:

> The window vector **must have n + 1 elements**.